# trigger in mysql update

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, mariadb

I have these tables and I want to write a trigger that, when I carry out an insert statement in "*tache*", given that `datedif(datestart,dateend) > 30`, I want to update table "*employe*" and set `salaire = salaire*0.5`

- Table 1: **employe** (mle, salaire)
- Table 2: **tache** (mle, datestart, dateend)

Here's my non-working attempt:

```
drop trigger if exists set_5_slr;

delimiter $$

create trigger set_5_slr 
before insert on réalise 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if datediff(new.dateDébut,new.datefin)>30 
    then UPDATE TABLE employé set salaire=salaire+(salaire*0.5)  where mle=new.mle;
    end if;
end ;

delimiter ;
```

Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: mysql <> mariadb, what's the DBMS you're currently using?

Comment: (#1) `before insert on réalise` non-described table. (#2) `datediff` will return `new.dateDébut - new.datefin` which seems to be negative. (#3) `salaire=salaire+(salaire*0.5)` is the same like `salaire=salaire*1.5`. (#4) `UPDATE TABLE employé` - incorrect syntax. (#5) `before insert on réalise .. UPDATE .. employé` - must be AFTER INSERT.

Comment: i have 2 tables employé ( mle ,salaire ) and tache (mle,datefin,datedebut) , ```create trigger set_5_slr after insert on réalise FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 if abs(datediff(new.dateDébut,new.datefin))>30 then 
   UPDATE employé set salaire=salaire*1.5  where mle=new.mle;
    end if;
end ;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is solution

```
delimiter $$
create TRIGGER réalise_AFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON réalise FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if abs(datediff(new.dateDébut,new.datefin))>30 then 
            UPDATE employé set salaire=salaire*1.5 where mle=new.mle;
    end if;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: *`abs(datediff(new.dateDébut,new.datefin))`* :facepalm: Must be `datediff(new.datefin,new.dateDébut)`.